# How do I append lines from one file to the end of each line of another file?

Tags: bash, append, line

Suppose I have two files:

```
cat
dog
baboon
```

```
feline
canine
primate
```

I want to append the lines from one file at the end of another file after adding a space. I know a way to do this using a for loop in bash, but I think there is a single command that can do this sort of thing, and I just can't remember it.

The output should look like:

```
cat feline
dog canine
baboon primate
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
paste --delimiter=' ' file1 file2
```

Note: the result will be written to stdout. If you want to store the result in a file, use a redirection operator:

```
paste --delimiter=' ' file1 file2 > outputfile
```

Run `man paste` for more information about the command.